# My manager is not assigning me a new concrete project and i am only getting other colleagues defects

Tags: software-industry, career-development

My manager is not assigning me any newer projects or modules to work on. I was working on one project and my colleagues were working on other projects. I finished my project and my colleagues finished theirs. But my colleagues have moved on to work on some different modules and I am only getting my defects and also their defects to work on. I have asked my manager about any new requirements, he said will see. He has also not directly asked me to work on the defects, but is asking other colleagues to assign me their defects.
How to deal with this. Is this normal or am I being sidetracked?

Comment: It is possible that he is getting you to fix the defects of your colleagues because he trusts you to do a good job of it.

Answer (score 3):

If I were in your shoes, I would set up a meeting with your manager to discuss what projects you want to be on as well as what he envisions you to complete and progress at the company. You should make your intentions clear on how you want to advance and what projects you want to work on. If he is able to agree with you, then that's a good sign. However, if you notice that nothing has changed after that meeting, then perhaps it is time to move on to other opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

**May be there is requirement for very few employees for that project that is assigned to your colleague and as soon as any new/fresh project comes, your manager may assign you to that project.**

Because in some cases, company does not have any fresh development work lined up or the some planning is yet to be done for new project. In this case manager has to managed their resources(employees) accordingly.

I think you should wait for few days, may be one or two week.

Then again approach your manager and ask him/her, Do we have any new projects lined up?

when you will get to work on new project instead of issue fixing?

If they have new project work and still your manager assigned that project to other colleague and not you, in this case you can always approach your HR Team. They are always there to sort kind of conflicts/situation.